# javascript closure not working with array properties?

Tags: javascript, closures

```
 var a = [false, 3];
 console.info('a: '+a);
     (function(item){
            var jamie = item;
        jamie [1]--;
         console.info('jamie:  '+jamie);
     })(a);
 console.info('a: '+a);
```

In my  mind `a[1]` should always equal 3 in this javascript.

And when not using an array it works as expected:

```
 var a = 3;
 console.info('b: '+a);
     (function(item){
            var jamie = item;
        jamie--;
         console.info('jamie b:  '+jamie);
     })(a);
```

console.info('b: '+a);

Why does `a[1]` output `2` after I have ran this JS? [Fiddle of said problem :O](http://jsfiddle.net/hutber/mK9Lz/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're providing a reference to the object not passing it by value;

If you want to clone the object, here is a helpful function to allow it:

```
function clone(obj) {
    if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;
    var copy = obj.constructor();
    for (var attr in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = obj[attr];
    }
    return copy;
}

var a = [false, 3];
console.info(a); // [false, 3];
    (function(item){
        var jamie = clone(item);
        jamie [1]--;
        console.log(jamie); // [false, 2];
    })(a);
console.info(a); // [false, 3];
```

Comment: He is passing "a" by value; its value is a reference to the array object.

Comment: Right, what Pointy said :)

Comment: Sorry to be so pedantic but blurring the meaning of the word "reference" with the term "pass by reference" has been driving me slightly crazy for decades :)

Comment: Boy I need to get better at JS.

Comment: heh, your "backwards" if statement variables threw me off. You sly cat

Comment: Literally copied from another SO answer at one point, never bothered to edit it haha

Comment: That this assumes a _constructor_ property (& that it is a constructor if it exists) bugs me for some reason

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with closures.

You're passing a reference to an array into a function, and the function is using that reference to alter the value of a property of the array.

When you assign an object (arrays are objects) to a variable, you're setting the value of the variable to a *reference* to the object.  You can't manipulate objects as values directly; all you have are references.

Comment: For clarity could you please explain how one might pass it by value and not by reference?

Comment: @JamieHutber you *are* passing by value. The value of variable "a" is a reference to the array. It is not possible to pass the array itself as a value without your explicitly making a copy of the array. (In that case, you'd be passing a reference to the copy of the array.)

Comment: I see, so because its an object (all objects are passed by reference) I can not pass it as a new value. Interesting, interesting that I knew this in theory. But this is the first time it has confused me. So to not alter the array's details I should put `a[1]` in as the value of the annoyomus function.

Comment: @JamieHutber yes, or pass `a.slice(0)` - that'd pass a *copy* (a shallow copy) of the array.